# Two words appear above each other inside the button in the material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

The word "Delete Workspace" appears on top of each other as it appears in the picture, where the word "Delete" appears in one line and the word "Workspace" in another line, and I want them to appear on the same line.

How can I solve the problem?

Within this file the interface shown in the image was designed and the "Delete Workspace" button was designed.

```js
import type { FC } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import { Avatar, Box, TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Settings: FC = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item md={12} xs={12}>
          <Box
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
          >
            <Avatar style={{ width: '5rem', height: '5rem' }} alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />

            <TextField
              fullWidth
              name="workspaceName"
              placeholder="Workspace Name"
              style={{
                paddingLeft: '1rem',
              }}
            />
          </Box>

          <Box
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            style={{
              marginTop: '6rem',
            }}
          >
            <Button
              style={{
                fontSize: '1.5rem',
                height: '44px',
                fontWeight: 400,
                textShadow: 'none',
                color: '#fd71af',
                border: 0,
                background: 'none',
              }}
            >
              Delete Workspace
            </Button>

            <Button
              color="primary"
              component={RouterLink}
              to="/dashboard/workspaces/1"
              variant="contained"
              style={{
                width: '17rem',
                height: '5.4rem',
                marginLeft: '70rem',
                fontSize: '1.8rem',
                backgroundColor: '#7b68ee',
                borderRadius: 6,
              }}
            >
              Saved
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Comment: Try to decrease marginLeft of your `saved` button

Comment: Thanks, I did it and it worked. @Priyank Kachhela